# Default movement keybindings for roguelike?

Tags: input, keyboard, roguelikes, mud

I'm developing a text based MUD, but unlike MUDs I'm developing without telnet and making a custom interface.  Think Caves of Qud or Dwarf Fortress.  The game only has 6 directions you can walk.  North, East, South, West, Up, Down.  So cardinal directions plus up and down.  The question is I want to map these directions to the numpad. But often these types of games include intermediate directions northeast, northwest, southeast, southwest so I'm not sure I should really use those keybindings from other games.  I could be wrong.  I don't know of any other games that use only the directions I'm using that also include a custom interface.  My personal feeling is the directions would be bound to the numpad as such, but if there is a kind of de facto standard out there I would prefer that.  I'm planning to add key rebindings, but I'm trying to figure what the default should be.

```
n = 8
e = 6
w = 4
s = 5
u = 9
d = 7
```

Comment: I'm not sure about a standard here. Just an aside in case you're planning to write any documentation/instructions/getting-started/in-game-introduction from a perspective that assumes the defaults. Keep in mind that some big fraction of laptop users (and even some desktop users) will lack a numpad.

Comment: @abathur Thanks for reminding me.  For that I was thinking of a setting with arrow keys and shift up and shift down for up and down.